# Export RTL view and Waveforms as images from Xilinx ISE webpack

Tags: xilinx

I think this is really a homework question, but moderators' call. I am trying to export the RTL view and waveforms of my verilog code into an image file (any format). But there doesn't seem any option to do that. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for **Print Screen**

Comment: @JoelB I hate Print Screen, hence the question.

Comment: Can you print postscript to a file?  (It may just embed at bitmap in the PS of course!)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem last year, and I believe that the only solution I found was to do a "Print Screen" to capture a bitmapped image.  Not as satisfying as a vector graphics export, but does the job.

Comment: :(, I hate printscreen.

Answer (score 1):

[This form](http://www.edaboard.com/thread205230.html) recommends using File->Print with a PDF printer setup. (e.g., `cups-pdf` on Linux.)

But [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419093/268066) suggests perhaps a better approach for the RTL, using alternative tools.

For the waveforms, printing to PDF works pretty well.  I changed the print options to use multiple pages so it didn't get all squashed, then followed [this advice](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18578) on using imagemagick to crop the top (the only used part) of each PDF page and stack them into a single PNG. Something like:

```
convert -density 100% infile.pdf[0,1] +adjoin -gravity north -crop 100%x20%+0+60 +repage -append outfile.png
```